# Is it correct to say "You got on my shoulders the other day and my back got hurt that night"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

On Monday afternoon last week, my children playfully got my my shoulders and on the evening of that day (about 11pm to about 1 or 2 am the next day) my back hurt.

Can we say "**that night**" to generally refer to the night that an event happened about 5-10 hours before that?

For example, "**You got on my shoulders the other day and my back got hurt that night**".

**Note**: the children got on my shoulders on the afternoon of that day and in the evening (5-10 hours later) I felt hurt. I did not feel hurt right at the time they got on my shoulders

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is one option. The most commonly used term in AmE (especially the south) is "the other night" instead of "the other day." so the sentence may say:

> When you got on my shoulders the other night and it hurt my back.

This is likely the most idiomatic way to say it, but your example is not wrong.

It is slightly odd that you want to mention both the time of the incident and the time that the pain started, but if that is your goal you may could say:

> After you got on my shoulders the other day my back started hurting a few hours later.

You can combine these two ideas to say:

> When you got on my shoulders the other day and it hurt my back. I started feeling pain later that night.

Note: it is better to say you **got hurt** and **felt pain**. **Feeling hurt** is not common phrasing.

Comment: No, I mean the children got on my shoulders on the afternoon of that day and in the evening I felt hurt. I did not feel hurt right at the time they got on my shoulders.

Comment: @Tom I know, but the action of **hurting** (the damage infliction) happened at the time they were on our shoulders.

Comment: Your back didn't **get** hurt during the night, it only **started** hurting then.

Comment: I did not feel anything then (at the time they got on) (I am 100% sure) and that is why I let them get on my shoulders. The pain happened 5-10 hours later when I lay down on my bed.

Comment: @Tom I understand, but **got hurt** refers to the incident that caused the issue. I think what you meant to say is "I started **feeling pain** that night." I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: The children climbing on your back hurt you or hurt your back. You got hurt when they climbed on your back. Eli is right, we don't say "feel hurt". We say feel pain.